# If I used Ejabberd authentication with JWT, I don't to need to register the user?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Currently, I have a social media project that already has the existing users, I want to enable the chat function. I had config Ejabberd with JWT and Mysql. I tested and I realized that I don't have to register the users in order to chat, I just need to make sure my token has "JID". Is it a good approach? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: did you find answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register the users to ejabberd server explicitly while using external authentication mechanism.
However, chances are that you might not be able to see the list of registered users on the admin panel when not using the default authentication mechanism.

Comment: How about security? Is it safe enough to follow it this way?